# Submitted form doesn't include the type='submit' parameters

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a big form with two submit buttons and I want to check on the backend which of the two buttons have been clicked. Even if I have done it many times in the past, this time, I have a strange issue. None of the two buttons are included in the post parameters.

Here is part of the form:

```
$html .= '<form type="post" action="" id="my_form">';
$html .= '<div class="form-action">';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addfrontenddata"/>';
$html .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit">';
$html .= '<a href="#" class="cancel-button">Cancel</a>';
$html .= '</div>';
$html .= '<div class="form-action">';  
$html .= '<input type="submit" name="draft" class="submit-button save-draft" value="Save Draft">';
$html .= '</div>';  
$html .= '</form>';
```

And my Wordpress code in the backend

```
$my_post['post_status'] = isset($_POST['draft']) ? 'draft' : get_option('default_status');
```

Neither the `$_POST['draft']` has a value, nor the parameters are there while I debug on the Chrome Console.

Comment: Do you get other fields value within this form?

Comment: Yes. All of them except the submit inputs.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code like in which hook you are adding your code?

Comment: It is in a custom plugin. The `post_status` is saved with the `get_option('default_status')`. But as I said, the two buttons are not passed from the parameters while I check the Chrome console. So, I don't think that it's the PHP code. But something in the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that your form type is set as post instead of form method being set as post.
Change below line

```
$html .= '<form type="post" action="" id="my_form">';
```

as

```
$html .= '<form method="post" action="" id="my_form">';
```

or simply use `$_GET[];`

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

name="submit" to name="whatever"

Comment: Nothing changed. I even removed that `name="submit"` since I only check for `draft` button